# pyspark cast multiple columns into different datatypes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Newbie to pyspark. I have a csv with multiple columns, with differing data-types, i.e. string, date, float, etc. I am reading all columns as StringType. How can I loop through the dataframe and cast these into respective data-types without having to write multiple withColumn statements. I have defined a dictionary like

```
conversions = {
    "COL1": lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL2":lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c,dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL3":lambda c: f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp(c,dateFormat)).cast("date"),
    "COL4":lambda c: f.col(c).cast("float"),
    "COL5":lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string"),
    "COL6":lambda c: f.col(c).cast("string")
}


for k,v in conversions.items():
    convDf = inputDf.withColumn(k,v(k))
```

This is not casting my input dates into correct format. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In each loop you overwrite confDf. Before the loop you should insert `convDf=inputDf` and within the loop `confDf=confDf.withColumn(...)`

Comment: great, that worked. Thanks